# SQL replace null with list of values

Tags: sql-server

I have a `City` and `StatePopulation` tables

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.City 
(
     Code INT, 
     CityName VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO CITY (CODE, CityName)
   select 1, 'Woodside'
   union
   select 2, 'Sunnyside'
   union
   select 3, 'Flushing'
   union
   select 4, 'Elmhurst'
   union
   select 5, 'ForestHills'
   union
   select 6, 'Manhattan'
   union
   select 7, 'Atlanta'
   union
   select 8, 'Alpharetta'
   union
   select 9, 'Johns Creek'

CREATE TABLE DBO.CityPopulation 
(
     StateCode VARCHAR(10), 
     CityCode INT, 
     PopulationCount INT
)

INSERT INTO DBO.CityPopulation (StateCode, CityCode, PopulationCount)
   SELECT 'NY', 1, 1000
   UNION
   SELECT 'NY', 2, 1500
   UNION
   SELECT 'NY', 3, 2500
   UNION
   SELECT 'NY', 4, 3000
   UNION
   SELECT 'NY', 5, 3500
   UNION
   SELECT 'NY', 6, 4000
   UNION
   SELECT 'GA', 7, 5500
   UNION
   SELECT 'GA', 8, 1200
   UNION
   SELECT 'GA', 9, 1900

CREATE TYPE dbo.UDTT_StateType AS TABLE (StateCode VARCHAR(10), CityCode INT)

DECLAR @State dbo.UDTT_StateType

INSERT INTO @State (StateCode, CityCode)
   select 'NY', null
   union
   select 'GA', 8
```

Now I need to return the rows from `CityPopulation` for the values in the `UDTT_StateType` that are matching on the `StateCode` and `CityCode`, but when the `StateCode` is 'NY' and the `City Code` is null, I need to return data for CityCode 1 and 2

Can anyone help me to write this query, please?

Comment: Why specifically 1 and 2 and not all for NY (1 to 6)?

Comment: Since I cannot edit the question anymore (my bad),  my result should return two rows with columns StateCode, CityCode, CityName, PopulationCount

Comment: You can always edit your question as the OP: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55091029/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with a CROSS JOIN.

```
SELECT cpd.StateCode, cpd.CityCode, cpd.CityName, cpd.PopulationCount 
FROM @State AS s 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM CityPopulation AS cp INNER JOIN city AS c ON cp.CityCode = c.Code 
                WHERE CityCode IN (1,2)) AS cpd 
WHERE s.CityCode = cpd.CityCode OR s.CityCode IS NULL
```

Which produced the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
select c.* from CityPopulation c,@State s where 
s.CityCode is null
And c.CityCode  in (1,2,3,4,5,6)                
And c.StateCode = s.StateCode
 Union 
select c.* from CityPopulation c,@State s where 
c.CityCode  =s.CityCode                
And c.StateCode = s.StateCode
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select c.*
from CityPopulation c, State s
where (
  (c.StateCode = s.StateCode and c.CityCode = s.CityCode)
  OR (s.StateCode = 'NY' and s.CityCode is null and (c.StateCode='NY' and c.CityCode in (1,2)))
)
```

Comment: Try to add some formatting to your SQL; whitespace and line breaks are really important to writing readable and manageable SQL. Also, you really should be using ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax, it's been available for 27 years. Adding some explanation of your answer also greatly helps the OP understand your answer. I suggest editting your answer to help make it better here. :)

Comment: Thank you, @coffeebeans for the quick response but I do not have the luxury of hard-coding the values because the query is the stored procedure which is using the UDTT as the parameter.  That was my problem!  I think I can make use CROSS JOIN here and come up with some solution.  Still working on it... :)